# How can I loop different where statements in the dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have multiple conditional where statements for the variables such as:

```
where 1<ColA<3;

where 4<ColB<6;

where 2<ColC<6;
.....
where 5<ColN<8;
```

I want to subset each of the datasets based on those where statements one by one like:

```
data newds1;
set original;
where 1<ColA<3;
run;

data newds2;
set original;
where 4<ColB<6;
run;

.....

data newdsn;
set original;
where 5<ColN<8;
run;
```

How can I do that in a loop in SAS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a macro to do the loop for you. You can pipe-separate all of your where statements and loop through each one.

```
%macro subset(data=, conditions=, out=);
    %let n = %sysfunc(countw(&conditions., |) );

    %do i = 1 %to &n.;
        %let where = %sysfunc(scan(&conditions., &i., |) );

        data &out.&i.;
            set &data.;
            where &where.;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;

%subset(data=original, conditions=1<ColA<3 | 4<ColB<6 | 2<ColC<6, out=newds);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is really close to what I'm looking for. Is variable out the datasets of the three conditions or what is that?

Comment: `out` is the base name of the dataset you want to output. In this case, it will create 3 datasets named `newds1`, `newds2`, and `newds3`